# Mongodb - Get value from of comment text if it was a quoted comment to another comment

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo db collection of comments. If a comment is quoted to another comment, I update `quoted: id of comment that was quoted`

I have the following query as demonstrated in the mongodb playground I created (link below).  In the example, comment333 has a quoted field value of 1 which means it was quoted to comment111.

How can the query be modified to include the "text" of the quoted comment if it was quoted?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/iUYzSBoKDNn

```
{
  commentedBy: "userfooid",
  "key": 1,
  "text": "content 111",
  "quoted": null,
  
},
{
  commentedBy: "userfooid",
  "key": 2,
  "text": "content 222",
  "quoted": null,
  
},
{
  commentedBy: "userf333",
  "key": 3,
  "text": "content 333",
  "quoted": 1,
```

The result I am looking for is the additional value `"quotedText": "content 111"`

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "commentedBy": "userf333",
    "key": 3,
    "quoted": 1,
    "text": "content 333"
    "quotedText": "content 111"

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `$lookup` for `comments`,

- `$match` `quoted` with `key`
- `$limit` if plausibility there are multiple comments by this id, i am not sure about this you can manage
- `$project` required fields

```
 {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      let: { quoted: "$quoted" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$quoted", "$key"] }
          }
        },
        { $limit: 1 },
        {
          $project: { _id: 0, text: 1 }
        }
      ],
      as: "quotedText"
    }
  },
```

- `$unwind` `quotedText` because its an array and we need only `text` field value
- `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` because there are possibility `quoted` will be null, this will ignore empty value

```
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$quotedText",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
```

- now we have object in `quotedText`
- `$addFields` for replace `quotedText` to `text`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      quotedText: "$quotedText.text"
    }
  }
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/V40_l71PN06

Comment: Do you use some kind of query generator or do you write these line by line?

Comment: no i am not using any query generator, just write line by line, most use of mongodb reference site, if you know the syntax then not needed any query generator.